# " . . . as construction teams complete/completing the bridge widening project"

Tags: as, participle-clauses

This sentence is correct:

> **Sentence A.**
>
> Expect transportation delays in Havering High Street next week **as** construction teams **complete** the bridge widening project."

But is this sentence also correct? I changed the clause "as~." into a participial phrase in Sentence B by changing the verb "complete" into "completing".

> **Sentence B.**
>
> Expect transportation delays in Havering High Street next week **as** construction teams **completing** the bridge widening project.

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The second clause

> construction teams completing the bridge widening project

has no verb. You would need to add something more:

> Expect transportation delays in Havering High Street next week as construction teams, **completing** the bridge widening project, will *close* one lane of traffic.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But a sentence like "I finished it after getting help from him." is correct. And there is no verb in "after getting help from him". I changed the sentence in the question like this. Would you give me more explanation about it?